# CKEDITOR 4.0 detach toolbar dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, toolbar

I am trying to figure out how to create a ckeditor instance with the toolbar attached to a seperate DIV from the DIV I am creating the instance on.  I see in the config array you can set config.sharedSpaces = { top: 'divid' } (at least in older versions you could), but I can't do that on the config page, it needs to be done on the page I am creating the instances on.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is how I am creating my instance:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
        toolbarGroups: [
            { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
            { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
            { name: 'colors' },
            { name: 'styles'},
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'align' ], items: [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote' ] },
            { items: [ 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar' ] },
            { name: 'links' },
            { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
            { name: 'tools'}
        ]
    });
```

Yes I do know I can use clone() and what not but I was hoping for a more clean solution.

Comment: This feature is already included in the version 4.1.
[CKEditor Shared Space](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace)

Answer (score 0):

The shared spaces feature is not available in CKEditor 4.0. It'll be reintroduced very soon in [CKEditor 4.1](https://dev.ckeditor.com/query?group=status&milestone=CKEditor+4.1) - see [the ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9387) (it's already merged to [major](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/major)).

Answer (score 0):

Before your initialize the editor, write this :

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.config.sharedSpaces = {
    'top' : 'myToolbar',
    };
</script>
```

If the sharedspaces plugin is not available download it from http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace

Answer (score 0):

For CKEditor 4.1+ you can use the optional [Shared Space](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) plugin (needs to be [added to your CKEditor build](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_plugins)).

```
<div id="top">
    <!-- This div will handle all toolbars. -->
</div>

<div>
    <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">My editor content</textarea>
</div>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        // Configure CKEditor to use the Shared Space plugin.
        extraPlugins: 'sharedspace',
        // The Resize plugin does not make sense in this context.
        removePlugins: 'resize',
        sharedSpaces: {
            // Configure the editor instance to place the toolbar in the div id='top'.
            top: 'top'
        }
    } );
</script>
```

See the ["Shared Toolbar and Bottom Bar" documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_sharedspace) with code examples and a [working demo](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html) with source code to copy & download.